# Ubuntu 21.10 freezes during boot when using nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, 21.10

First time actually asking a question here, but I've dug through 20 or so threads on this forum and others and can't find anything.

Basically, the issue is that when I try to use my GPU on my laptop (an ACER Predator, the GPU is an RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q), it freezes on the startup screen (specifically the Predator logo above the Ubuntu logo, no spinning dots).

It does this when I use any proprietary driver, including all of these:
[The Software & Updates window showing the Additional Drivers tab. It shows the device, "NVIDIA Corporation: GA106M GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q", and then the options for drivers below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zq63.png)
and installing `nvidia-driver-460` from the command line. All of them freeze in the same place when booting.
Adding `nomodeset` in GRUB hasn't worked as a temporary or permanent solution, but booting with the other kernel option GRUB provides (5.13.0-23 instead of 5.12.0-25) does get me in when using the `nvidia-driver-460-server` driver. It's a bit buggy though, with missing animations in GNOME and some other issues. Also, I can't actually *use* the drivers- NVIDIA Prime is missing.

My current method of fixing the problem each time so I can try something else is by using GRUB to get into recovery mode and doing `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*`, then rebooting. None of the `ctrl`+`alt`+`f1` keys work when it freezes.

Let me know if you have anything else I can try, or need any more information. I've tried a lot of things, and some of them probably escape me right now. I also did have it working for a little bit, but when I restarted my computer it was broken again and I honestly forget what it was I did back then. Thank you!

Comment: Given [Ubuntu 21.04 is in it's last few days of support](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html) I'd not spend much effort in getting it working.  With *drivers* being kernel modules; you'll be *release-upgrading* within a week to a new system & thus new kernel & kernel modules... so try staring with a release that has support after 21 January 2022 unless you intend to retire your box on 20-January when 21.04 reaches it's EOL.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. Thanks! I'll switch up to that and give it a try. In the meantime, if anyone has anything else to add, it would still be appreciated. Never know when someone might have the same problem and need to be on this version for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Never mind. Turns out I wasn't paying attention, and I am on 21.10. Need to pay closer attention to my updates. Going to edit this thread with the same question if that's possible, otherwise I'll move it to a new topic. Edit: Updated the numbers. Sorry about that, still unfamiliar with StackExchange for the most part.

Comment: Have you always had this problem or did it start recently?

Comment: Since I switched this machine to Ubuntu from Windows. I was using the integrated graphics for a little bit, and probably first tried to use the Nvidia card shortly after the 21.10 update.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI? You should.

Comment: Yes, secure boot has been disabled since before I started trying to install the drivers.

Comment: I have been having the same issue in Ubuntu 20, I have revert to a older version of the kernel to solve this (5.8.0-53-generic), not the greatest solution. But it's something.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I solved it by installing the `liquorix kernel` as indicated here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/mouse-freezes-geforce-rtx-3060-with-either-ubuntu-22-04-or-mint-21/227375/4

This is the website of the liquorix kernel: https://liquorix.net/

> Liquorix is a distro kernel replacement built using the best configuration and kernel sources for desktop, multimedia, and gaming workloads.

This installation instructions for Ubuntu are:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damentz/liquorix && sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install linux-image-liquorix-amd64 linux-headers-liquorix-amd64`

After installing the liquorix kernel, I installed the latest nvidia driver, which by the time of this writing was (nvidia-driver-520):

1. `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520`

Hope it helps.

Update:

There is one more thing I found to help in this issue. After executing the steps mentioned above, do the following:

Go to settings -> power and set the options this way:

[image: power settings]

Why?

It seems like the issue is related to the drivers or the power supply of the graphics card. After applying these settings it hasn't frozen.

This also happens on Windows, see: https://www.dell.com/community/Alienware-Desktops/Aurora-R12-keeps-freezing/td-p/8154258