# Ubuntu freezes when running any game

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, freeze, crash

Running Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS desktop with Kernel 5.18 on a Razer Blade 2022 laptop.It has 12th gen Intel i9, GEforce RTX 3080Ti, Quad 240Hz display, 36 GB RAM, 1TB SSD if that helps.
The whole system locks up/freeze when running a game. Doesn't matter what game. The only way to revive it is to power it off and reboot. I checked the log file but it does not show any errors.

If it helps I am using the Nvidia driver 515.76. The generic one didn't work well. I tried running different desktop environments to figure out if GNOME was the issue, but it isn't.

Anything I can do or look for to figure out why it freezes up? Thx

Comment: Please be specific with details; I'd be guessing given the '*vague*' terms you use & thus will just bypass this question. For specific advice, you need to be specific with details.

Comment: Details need to be specific; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server both use the 5.15 kernel by default; you didn't specify which but do mention a non-Ubuntu kernel (*unless using an OEM kernel which you didn't specify, nor is the edge kernel option*).   Are you using Ubuntu? as 5.18 kernel doesn't match 22.04 LTS but a non-Ubuntu like Pop OS 22.04 ?  That is off-topic here (*Pop OS isn't Ubuntu*)

Comment: The link you provide says in clear bold "*NOTE: The Mainline Kernel package does not include any Ubuntu-provided drivers or patches, which are NOT appropriate for production use*" so you've replaced Ubuntu with your upstream kernel choice and problems can be expected with your non-Ubuntu choice (*it was a testing kernel only for Ubuntu*). The *edge* kernel for 22.04 LTS is 5.19 so why use a non-Ubuntu 5.18 seems strange to me  (*also I don't know what Unubuntu is; this is a Ubuntu site*)

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Ok thanks. Update my post for clarity and info.

Comment: I should clarify the the error occurred with 5.19 which is why I tried 5.18. It didn't help though. The whole system still freezes up within 20 minutes if running any game.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and documented how I solved here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1442478/118029. Hope it helps.